# Camel bean binding: set parameter from variable

Tags: apache-camel

Given a bean method that takes a String parameter:

```
public void emptyDirectory(String directory) {
   // code to empty give directory if it exists
}
```

how do i pass this parameter? The method is called here:

```
String to = configuration.getTo();

from(configuration.getFrom())
     .to("bean:splitFileByProductType?method=emptyDirectory(to)")
     ....
```

This doesn't work as 'to' evaluates to "to", and not the value of *configuration.getTo()*.

The [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.1/html/Implementing_Enterprise_Integration_Patterns/files/BasicPrinciples-BeanIntegration.html) does not mention a case like this, so i don't know if what i'm trying to do is even possible, for example in the [Simple](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) language.

I know the value becomes accessible if i add it to the exchange header or if i hardcode it.

Comment: have u seen this documentation ? http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html

Comment: @Aku I think its the same as what i link to, but without the frame for easy navigation.

Comment: You could assign the parameter to an exchange header or property in a processor and then use simple language to pass it the bean method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html):
The only things that can be passed to a bean are Simple tokens, a String value, a numeric value, a boolean or null.

The variable from the example cannot be expressed using [Simple](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html). What can be expressed are various properties of the exchange, most notably the exchange headers, and also some random things like literally random numbers, the current date and so on. Check the documentation for more info.

I decided to treat the whole thing as a code smell, and moved the method to a utility class which i call prior to initializing the route.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a value as method argument with ${body}, ${body.NAME}, ${property.NAME} and ${header.NAME}.

Examples http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html

So first of all you have to put your variable in Camel exchange.

Comment: Sure, but you can also pass booleans, integers or Strings directly. So my question is, can i pass an expression that evaluates to a String?

Answer (score 2):

To pass information **from the Camel Exchange to a bean method** you must not add or change anything in the route.

If you have this route (from your question). Notice that if the bean has only one method you can omit the method name.

```
from(whatever)
    .to("bean:splitFileByProductType?methodName=emptyDirectory")
```

Or alternative

```
from(whatever)
    .bean(splitFileByProductType, "emptyDirectory")
```

You can annotate your bean method to get the needed Exchange information automagically:

```
public void emptyDirectory(
    @Header("directory") String directory, 
    @Body String body
    ... [other stuff to be injected] ) {

// your method impl
}
```

See the [Camel docs](http://camel.apache.org/parameter-binding-annotations.html) for more information about this feature.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the annotation option, i didnt know about that one. But it still means getting values from the header.

Comment: Yeah, because a bean parameter is typically dynamic (different for every message). If the value is constant (same for all messages), I would not pass it at all, but inject it directly into the bean.

Answer (score 1):

You could assign the parameter to an exchange header or property and then use simple language to pass it the bean method

```
   String to = configuration.getTo();

    from(configuration.getFrom())
            .setHeader("foo", constant(to))
            .to("bean:splitFileByProductType?method=emptyDirectory(${header.foo})")
            ...
```